# How can I improve query performance?

Tags: powerquery, m

I am running the following query against a source table that is 3 columns by 37,636 rows and it is taking hours to run. How might I improve the performance?

The source table is, itself, the result of a precedent query, in case that matters. The precedent queries execute in a reasonable amount of time (in minutes) but this one bogs down badly.

The source table's column names are Columns, Columns2, and Count.

```
let
Source = Table.Buffer(GetWordCounts),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Buffer(Table.Group(Source, {"Count"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table}})),
Custom1 = Table.Buffer(Table.MaxN(#"Grouped Rows","Count",10)),
#"Expanded AllData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Custom1, "AllData", {"Columns", "Columns2"}, {"Columns", "Columns2"})
in
#"Expanded AllData"
```

I tried adding `Table.Buffer` in a few places, as you can see, but I can't tell if it is helping or hurting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With the same amount of test data in Excel, it runs with me within about 2 seconds. If you isolate the input for this query in a separate Excel worbook or pbix file, do you still have the same bad performance? I suspect the bad performance is due to previous steps.

*Edit: alternative code you may give a try:*

```
let
    Source = Table.Buffer(GetWordCounts),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source, {"Count"})[Count],
    Max10 = List.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",Order.Descending){9},
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Count] >= Max10)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcelBeug. I tried an isolated run of the original query in Excel and, like you, I saw a very quick result. So then I started stepping through the precedent queries and I _think_ I may have found the issue...but I'm not sure why it is a problem or how to solve it. It has to do with this earlier solution you provided me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395636/compare-each-columns-contents-with-all-other-columns-contents-and-present-matr/44402603#44402603). It seems things bog down real bad at `Tabled = Table.FromColumns({ColumnNames}, type table[Columns = text]),`.

Comment: Just as a shot in the dark, I unchecked "Allow data preview to download in the background" and "Enable parallel loading of tables" and it seemed to make things go a lot quicker right up to the originally stated trouble spot...#"Grouped Rows" (or the #"Removed Duplicates" in your alternative). It takes less than 2 minutes to get through Tabled, but it bogs down at the #"Grouped Rows (or #"Removed Duplicates"). It is taking hours. Now I'm thinking that means Tabled may not be part of the problem after all. I'm _really_ stumped.